# What is the right way to compare dates in Ecto

Tags: elixir, ecto

What is the right way to compare dates in range, using the minus operator and comparing if the date is greater than in Ecto ?

```
  def has_valid_date_range(query) do
    from ct in query,
      where: (ct.end_date - from_now(0, "day")) > 0,
      where: (ct.end_date - from_now(0, "day")) <= ct.due_notice
  end
```

The result for this query should return all rows where the end_date minus today is greater than 0 and end_date minus today is lower than due_notice

But it returns me an error

`** (Ecto.Query.CompileError) ct.end_date() - from_now(0, "day") is not a valid query expression.`

Comment: What exactly are you trying to calculate here? `from_now` only works with comparison operators in the Ecto DSL as far as I know. You're probably looking for `datetime_add`.

Comment: I was reading the documentation, but I did'nt see the `from_now` comparing with `-` function. Probably you are right. Is there an alternative way to make build this query ?

Comment: What is the type of `due_notice` here? What are you trying to calculate?

Comment: Sorry, I forget to mention the types, `due_notice` is an `integer`

Comment: And that's the number of days? Does this work? `where: ct.end_date > from_now(0, "day") and ct.end_date <= datetime_add(ct.end_date, ct.due_notice, "month")`?

Comment: Your answer solved my question, with a small change from `month` to `day`. `where: ct.end_date > from_now(0, "day") and ct.end_date <= datetime_add(ct.end_date, ct.due_notice, "day")`. Thank you very much, if you don't mind to post the answer.

Comment: Posted :) I would suggest posting a description of the behavior you want in English as well if your code doesn't do what you want it to do or it's hard to figure it out by just looking at the not working code. For this question, it could have been: `select the records whose end_date is after the current time and before due_notice days from the current time`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As we figured out in the comment section, you wanted to select the records whose `end_date` was after the current time and before `due_notice` days from the current time. For that, you can use this query:

```
where: ct.end_date > from_now(0, "day") and
       ct.end_date <= datetime_add(ct.end_date, ct.due_notice, "day")
```